# ¿Adjetivo para el invierno?

Tags: vocabulario, adjetivos

Así como he escuchado *veraniego* y *primaveral*, ¿existen similares para otoño e invierno? El último me resulta más importante.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Otoñal** e **invernal**.
Para el verano también se usa **estival**.

**Edición**: Encontré estos cultismos (palabras apegadas al origen etimológico, en este caso al latín):

Para el verano: estial

Para la primavera : vernal (qué curioso)

Para el invierno: hibernal

Son palabras del español que se pueden encontrar en escritos antiguos, están en desuso. Pero "hibernal" todavía existe en la terminología de los ecólogos.

Comment: Vernal viene de la palabra latina por primavera «ver».  Verano viene de «veranum», por tanto sería «veranal» si existiese con «-al».  Lo curioso es que para ti hibernal parezca más común jaja yo nunca la uso pero sí uso con frecuencia estival y vernal.

Comment: Con las ediciones ha quedado una contradicción. Por un lado, se dice que *estival* se usa para el verano; por otro, que está en desuso. En realidad, *estival* se sigue utilizando con frecuencia.

Comment: Estival no está en desuso. La palabra en desuso es "estial", sin la "v".

Comment: @Guifa, es verdad que nadie usa "hibernal". Lo que sí se usa en ecología, como palabra técnica, es "hibernación", pero no se refiere al invierno sino a un periodo de letargo en algunos animales y semillas. Si no me equivoco, también tiene que ver con computadores.

Comment: En inglés, la frase "vernal equinox" se refiere al comienzo de primavera.  Viene del mismo origen.

Comment: Como dato complementario, el momento exacto de la entrada de la primavera se define astronómicamente por la pasada por el "punto vernal" :)

Answer (score 1):

La excepción es el verano, para el resto es *+al*

Otoñal, invernal y primaveral, inclusive estival de estío.